# Custom HTML tags in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm trying to recreate an HTML page in Visualforce that has custom HTML tags (e.g. `<mytag:blah name='todd'></mytag:blah>`) which are grabbed via a JavaScript callout in the same page.

Salesforce doesn't seem to like these, erring "Unknown component mytag:blah".

Is there a simple way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce will not allow you to use tag in this format because value before colon `:` is reserved for package **Namespace** and value after colon `:` is for **Visualforce Component's name**. If you want, you will have to have that namespace and `</apex:component>` in org with name which would not be easier.

The only way you can do it change `:` with `-` or any symbol.

```
<apex:page >
    <tag-blah>Hello, this is my invention!</tag-blah>
</apex:page>
```

However, this is *re-inventing of [ReactJs](https://facebook.github.io/react/)*